# Telerik Grid with Repeated columns

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a table which have ID, Name, Value as columns. I have 12 records in the table which needs to be bind in the grid. The grid shows the data like below

Name  Value        Name   Value       Name Value

So the same set of columns need to be repeated 3 times so totally 4 rows shows the full data. How can I do it with Telerik RadGrid?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without create `new DataSet/DataTable` of 6 column...Must use RadGrid ?

Comment: Try add `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` in radgrid Attributes...

Comment: Not sure but you can achieve this thing by using 'rad pivot grid'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat columns, just declare them as many times as you want (even though the goal is a bit beyond me). Here is an example:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DocumentID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Filename"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DocumentID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Filename"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DocumentID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Filename"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

and here is a dummy data source:

```
protected DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DocumentID"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Filename"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UploadedBy"));
    tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { "firstRecord1", "firstRecord2", "firstRecord3", "firstRecord4" });
    tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { "secondRecord1", "secondRecord2", "secondRecord3", "secondRecord4" });
    tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { "thirdRecord1", "thirdRecord2", "thirdRecord3", "thirdRecord4" });
    tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { "fourthRecord1", "fourthRecord2", "fourthRecord3", "fourthRecord4" });

    return tbl;
}

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.DataSource = GetData();
}
```

If I have misunderstood, and you actually want different layout - you should use a **RadListView** control where you can define your own layout (e.g., floated divs with the desired content).